# Centering OutputText on a VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce, style

I am attempting to put a text message just above the buttons of some of the records which will indicate to the user that something is still needed in order to Submit his request. For some reason my text will not center properly. I thought maybe it was because I am trying to do it at the very top of the record, and maybe that was impossible in that section. But I tried moving it to other parts of the record and it wouldn't work either.

Here is the top portion of the VisualForce code which contains my style and outputtext :

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Product_Review__c">

    <head>     
     <style >
        italicText 
        { 
            font-style: italic; 
            font-weight: bold
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align:center;
            **width :100%;**
        }                   
     </style>
    </head>

<apex:messages />

    <apex:sectionheader title="{!$ObjectType.Product_Review__c.label} Detail" subtitle="{!Product_Review__c.Name}"/>
    <chatter:feedwithfollowers entityId="{!Product_Review__c.Id}"/>
    <apex:form >
    <div style="text-align:center;font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold ; color : #FF0000">
           <apex:outputText value="{!Product_Review__c.Docs_Still_Needed__c}" rendered="{!IF(Vendor_Product_Review__c.Docs_Still_Needed__c = '', false, true)}"  /> 
       </div>
        <apex:pageblock mode="maindetail" title="{!$ObjectType.Product_Review__c.label} Detail">
            <apex:pageblockbuttons >
                <apex:commandbutton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}"/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Delete" action="{!Delete}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Submit for Approval" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Product_Review__c.submit, Id)}" id="Submit_for_Approval" rendered="{!IF(Product_Review__c.Status__c = 'Approved', false, true)}"/>

            </apex:pageblockbuttons>
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You will only center something on the *page* with the `text-align` property if your element `width` is 100%. So make sure to add `width: 100%`. Pure css questions should be asked on [so].

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Thank you very much for your input. I wasn't sure if this was a problem the location of the outputtext on the Salesforce VF page or a purely css question. I attempted to put the width="100%" in both the <style> and the outputtext line but am only getting errors. Where does that need to go ? (I edited my code above to show changes I attempted with **). Thanks again for any help you can give. I'm sorry if this is out of place here on the SF forum.

Comment: It's `:`, not `=`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - thank you again. I made the changes but the outputtext is still not centering. The changes are as shown in the post (without the asterisks). Thank you.

Comment: Read up on [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). If you `investigate element`, you will probably find that the styles you are trying to apply are being ignored. Try to add more specificity to your selector than just `italicText`, which should really be `.italicText`. As a *last resort*, you can try adding `!important` to some of the styles.

Comment: I got help from somebody and apparently it was a Salesforce-specific styling issue, not a pure csss question. I have updated the code above to show the proper syntax.